# Sending custom name and viewing it on analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

I want to send the custom name of the link clicked by user.
Iam using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22140531-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'landline','acct_Summary',2]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Telemedia','bill_guide']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 
    '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script
```

Is the above script correct for what iam trying to do??
Also how will i see these custom values in the GA account??
Anyone please help as iam stuck badly in my project due to this.